# Jmeter slowly consuming all memory with only 1 thread

Tags: jmeter

I am running jmeter with only one thread and it is still eventually consuming all available memory. The test is running gets, heads and puts from a large csv file >3mil rows. Some of these files are large (> 1gb) but most are average sizes, regardless of that, it seems to die well before it gets to those huge files anyway.

I have all listeners disabled and running from the console, which should also reduce the overhead. I have also given the heap 10G of memory which I would think is plenty?

I have attached the jmx file if that helps:

[jmx runfile](https://gist.github.com/donkeyx/b7b268f8858094dc3db045443fc536ba)

Is there some process i can run to cleanup/purge as its processing, or am I doing something wrong in the plan its self.

sample csv:

```
PUT,500,path_name_here,filename_1,replication=false
GET,1500,path_name_here,filename_2,allowredirect=true
GET,500,path_name_here,filename_3,allowredirect=true
```

Comment: Your link is broken.CSV is configuration which is loaded first. If you disable the 1giga file is it still happening?

Comment: I just fixed the link, and no it still seems to continue to grow. I am wondering how its handling the get downloads, maybe they are stored in mem, or take too long to get gc'ed

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be suffering from the problem described [here](http://www.jmeter-archive.org/fileupload-test-with-JMeter-td4267154.html), try switching to the [HTTP Raw Request](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/RawRequest/) which can upload large files without loading them fully into memory.

You can install HTTP Raw Request sampler using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-install-jmeter-plugins-manager):

[image: JMeter Plugins Manager]